# How to update variable from TextFormField in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have TextFormField which has its own controller. I also have a disabled button that I would like to enable after any input inside TextFormField. The problem is that I managed to enable the button however only when I close the keyboard. For example, if I'm typing a word in a session it won't enable the button unless I close the keyboard. I would like to enable the button after the first character.

This is the code:

```
final TextEditingController passwordController = new TextEditingController();

TextFormField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
  controller: passwordController,
),

RaisedButton(
  onPressed: (passwordController.text== "") ? null : () {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });
    signIn(email, passwordController.text);
  },
),
```

Comment: You could simply use the `onChange(value)` callback from the [TextFormField](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField-class.html).

Comment: I was going to say that didn't work either, but then I realized that I forgot to setState. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked:

```
var password = '';

TextFormField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
  controller: passwordController,
  onChanged: (value){
    setState(() {
      password = value;
    });
  },
),

RaisedButton(
  onPressed: (password == "") ? null : () {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });
    signIn(email, password);
  },
),
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
bool _isLoading = true;

// it tracks if TextField is enabled or disabled
bool _enabled = false;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  _controller.addListener(() { // you need to add listener like this
    setState(() {
      if (_controller.text.length > 0)
        _enabled = true;
      else
        _enabled = false;
    });
  });
}

Widget build(context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(height: 50),
        TextFormField(controller: _controller),
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: !_enabled ? null : () => setState(() => _isLoading = true),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Not quite. _isLoading is used for showing loading bar while async sign-in is processing.

Comment: @Sprowk Ok, I changed the code accordingly, please check out the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you're looking for, I created a boolean called `isEnabled` and set the initial value to `false`. This should work for you!

```
bool isEnabled;
final TextEditingController passwordController = new TextEditingController();

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  passwordController.addListener(() {
    setState(() {
      if (passwordController.text.length > 0) {
        isEnabled = true;
      } else {
        isEnabled = false;
      }
    });
  });
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        TextFormField(
          keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
          controller: passwordController,
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Click Me'),
          onPressed: isEnabled ? () {
            //print('Button has been pressed');
            setState(() {
              _isLoading = true;
            });
            signIn(email, passwordController.text);
          } : null,
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```